# Expected concrete lifetime, found bound lifetime parameter when storing a fn in a struct

Tags: rust

I'm trying to store a function in a struct:

```
trait T<'a> {}

struct A {}

struct B<'a> {
    a: &'a A
}

impl<'a> T<'a> for B<'a> {}

fn f1<'a, E: T<'a>>(a: &'a A) {}

struct D {
    f: fn(&A)
}

fn main() {
    let d = D { f: f1::<B> };
}
```

The compiler complains:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:18:20
   |
18 |     let d = D { f: f1::<B> };
   |                    ^^^^^^^ expected concrete lifetime, found bound lifetime parameter 
   |
   = note: expected type `fn(&A)`
   = note:    found type `fn(&A) {f1::<'_, B<'_>>}`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write `f1::<B>`, the compiler interprets that as `f1::<B<'_>>`, there `'_` is a lifetime inferred by the compiler, because `B` is generic over a lifetime and you can only pass concrete types as type parameters.

But then, in `D`, the `f` field is expected to be a function that accepts references to `A` with any lifetime. `f1::<B>` does not fulfill that requirement, because the function has been instantiated with a specific lifetime.

Unfortunately, at the moment, there's no way to make this work. Rust would have to support either [higher kinded types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kind_%28type_theory%29) or [associated type constructors](https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/blog-post-series-alternative-type-constructors-and-hkt/4300). You could then define `E` in `f1` to be a type constructor parameter, rather than a type parameter (though I'm wondering how the compiler would handle the `'a` lifetime parameter).

Comment: I think you're right, but it didn't stop me from trying to use `for<'a> ...` in a few ways to get around it.  :-)

Comment: I've read something about for<'a>, but found no way to get around it. May I know how do you do it?

Comment: @Cheng-ChangWu: What Chris was saying is that he tried using `for<'a>...` to solve your problem, but unfortunately it doesn't work here. For the record, in `D`, `f: fn(&A)` is a shorthand for `f: for<'a> fn(&'a A)`.