# Implementing trait for Fn(&something) in Rust

Tags: rust, traits, lifetime

Here is a working sample to implement `Runnable` for `Fn()` (so that we can directly pass a &closure to the `run_the_runnable` function):

```
trait Runnable {
    fn run(&self);
}

impl<F> Runnable for F where F: Fn() {
    fn run(&self) {
        self();
    }
}

fn run_the_runnable(runnable: &Runnable) {
    runnable.run();
}

fn main() {
    // runnable without parameters
    struct MyRunnable;
    impl Runnable for MyRunnable {
        fn run(&self) {
            println!("Hello from MyRunnable");
        }
    }

    // from struct instance (WORKS)
    run_the_runnable(&MyRunnable);

    // from closure (WORKS)
    run_the_runnable(&|| {
        println!("Hello from run() closure");
    });
}
```

([Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=trait%20Runnable%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20run%28%26self%29%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aimpl%3CF%3E%20Runnable%20for%20F%20where%20F%3A%20Fn%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20run%28%26self%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self%28%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20run_the_runnable%28runnable%3A%20%26Runnable%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20runnable.run%28%29%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20main%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20runnable%20without%20parameters%0A%20%20%20%20struct%20MyRunnable%3B%0A%20%20%20%20impl%20Runnable%20for%20MyRunnable%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fn%20run%28%26self%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20println!%28%22Hello%20from%20MyRunnable%22%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20from%20struct%20instance%20%28WORKS%29%0A%20%20%20%20run_the_runnable%28%26MyRunnable%29%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20from%20closure%20%28WORKS%29%0A%20%20%20%20run_the_runnable%28%26%7C%7C%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20println!%28%22Hello%20from%20run%28%29%20closure%22%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%29%3B%0A%7D&version=stable&backtrace=0))

Now, let's change the runnable `run()` method to accept a reference parameter (`&i32`), and implement `Fn(&i32)`:

```
trait Runnable {
    fn run(&self, x: &i32);
}

impl<F> Runnable for F where F: Fn(&i32) {
    fn run(&self, x: &i32) {
        self(x);
    }
}

fn run_the_runnable(runnable: &Runnable, x: &i32) {
    runnable.run(x);
}

fn main() {
    // runnable without parameters
    struct MyRunnable;
    impl Runnable for MyRunnable {
        fn run(&self, x: &i32) {
            println!("Hello from MyRunnable {}", x);
        }
    }

    let x = 42;

    // from struct instance (WORKS)
    run_the_runnable(&MyRunnable, &x);

    // from closure (DOES NOT WORK)
    run_the_runnable(&|x| {
        println!("Hello from run(&i32) closure {}", x);
    }, &x);
}
```

([Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=trait%20Runnable%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20run%28%26self%2C%20x%3A%20%26i32%29%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aimpl%3CF%3E%20Runnable%20for%20F%20where%20F%3A%20Fn%28%26i32%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20run%28%26self%2C%20x%3A%20%26i32%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self%28x%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20run_the_runnable%28runnable%3A%20%26Runnable%2C%20x%3A%20%26i32%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20runnable.run%28x%29%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20main%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20runnable%20without%20parameters%0A%20%20%20%20struct%20MyRunnable%3B%0A%20%20%20%20impl%20Runnable%20for%20MyRunnable%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fn%20run%28%26self%2C%20x%3A%20%26i32%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20println!%28%22Hello%20from%20MyRunnable%20%7B%7D%22%2C%20x%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20let%20x%20%3D%2042%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20from%20struct%20instance%20%28WORKS%29%0A%20%20%20%20run_the_runnable%28%26MyRunnable%2C%20%26x%29%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20from%20closure%20%28DOES%20NOT%20WORK%29%0A%20%20%20%20run_the_runnable%28%26%7Cx%7C%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20println!%28%22Hello%20from%20run%28%26i32%29%20closure%20%7B%7D%22%2C%20x%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%20%26x%29%3B%0A%7D&version=stable&backtrace=0))

Passing the closure does not work anymore:

```
error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `for<'r> <[closure@<anon>:30:27: 32:10] as std::ops::FnOnce<(&'r i32,)>>::Output == ()`
  --> <anon>:30:26
   |
30 |           run_the_runnable(&|x| {
   |  __________________________^ starting here...
31 | |             println!("Hello from run(&i32) closure {}", x);
32 | |         }, &x);
   | |_________^ ...ending here: expected bound lifetime parameter , found concrete lifetime
   |
   = note: concrete lifetime that was found is lifetime '_#63r
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Runnable` for `[closure@<anon>:30:27: 32:10]`
   = note: required for the cast to the object type `Runnable`

error[E0281]: type mismatch: the type `[closure@<anon>:30:27: 32:10]` implements the trait `std::ops::Fn<(_,)>`, but the trait `for<'r> std::ops::Fn<(&'r i32,)>` is required (expected concrete lifetime, found bound lifetime parameter )
  --> <anon>:30:26
   |
30 |           run_the_runnable(&|x| {
   |  __________________________^ starting here...
31 | |             println!("Hello from run(&i32) closure {}", x);
32 | |         }, &x);
   | |_________^ ...ending here
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Runnable` for `[closure@<anon>:30:27: 32:10]`
   = note: required for the cast to the object type `Runnable`
```

There are many questions about this error:

- [Expected concrete lifetime, found bound lifetime parameter when storing a fn in a struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41087239/expected-concrete-lifetime-found-bound-lifetime-parameter-when-storing-a-fn-in)
- [Expected bound lifetime parameter, found concrete lifetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32194367/expected-bound-lifetime-parameter-found-concrete-lifetime)
- [Rust lifetime error expected concrete lifetime but found bound lifetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24847331/rust-lifetime-error-expected-concrete-lifetime-but-found-bound-lifetime)
- …

But I am still not able to resolve this specific lifetime problem.

Comment: Adding explicit type annotations help. For example, saying `&|x: &i32| { ... }` already solves the problem. Rust seems to have problems inferring types in these situations :/ at least that's what *I* think the problem is.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44003622/implementing-trait-for-fnsomething-in-rust#comment75036233_44003622), giving the explicit type in the closure parameters fixes the issue:

```
@@ -26,8 +26,8 @@ fn main() {
     // from struct instance (WORKS)
     run_the_runnable(&MyRunnable, &x);

-    // from closure (DOES NOT WORK)
-    run_the_runnable(&|x| {
+    // from closure with annotated type (WORKS)
+    run_the_runnable(&|x: &i32| {
         println!("Hello from run(&i32) closure {}", x);
     }, &x);
 }
```

([Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=trait%20Runnable%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20run%28%26self%2C%20x%3A%20%26i32%29%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aimpl%3CF%3E%20Runnable%20for%20F%20where%20F%3A%20Fn%28%26i32%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20run%28%26self%2C%20x%3A%20%26i32%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self%28x%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20run_the_runnable%28runnable%3A%20%26Runnable%2C%20x%3A%20%26i32%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20runnable.run%28x%29%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20main%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20runnable%20without%20parameters%0A%20%20%20%20struct%20MyRunnable%3B%0A%20%20%20%20impl%20Runnable%20for%20MyRunnable%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fn%20run%28%26self%2C%20x%3A%20%26i32%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20println!%28%22Hello%20from%20MyRunnable%20%7B%7D%22%2C%20x%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20let%20x%20%3D%2042%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20from%20struct%20instance%20%28WORKS%29%0A%20%20%20%20run_the_runnable%28%26MyRunnable%2C%20%26x%29%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20from%20closure%20%28DOES%20NOT%20WORK%29%0A%20%20%20%20run_the_runnable%28%26%7Cx%3A%20%26i32%7C%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20println!%28%22Hello%20from%20run%28%26i32%29%20closure%20%7B%7D%22%2C%20x%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%20%26x%29%3B%0A%7D&version=stable&backtrace=0))